# Why matplotlib chart display gaps when there is no available data in pandas dataframe indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have code like this

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pytz
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

start_datetime = dt(2020, 5, 6) 
end_datetime = dt(2020, 5, 12)
symbol = "EURUSD"

mt5.initialize()
timezone = pytz.timezone('Etc/UTC')
utc_from = dt(start_datetime.year, start_datetime.month, start_datetime.day, 00, 00, tzinfo=timezone)
utc_to = dt(end_datetime.year, end_datetime.month, end_datetime.day, 23, 59, tzinfo=timezone)
rates = mt5.copy_rates_range(symbol, mt5.TIMEFRAME_H1, utc_from, utc_to)
mt5.shutdown()

df = pd.DataFrame(rates)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s') 
df.set_index('time', inplace = True)

df['change%'] = ((df['high'] - df['low']) / df['low'])*100
df = df[['change%']] 
print(df)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
plt.plot(df.index.values, df['change%'], label = 'change%', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(45)

plt.show()
```

It generate this kind of graph.

[image: graph]

but i don't need to display the gap inside red box because there is no data within that dates. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It treats the x-axis as dates and it makes them evenly spaced

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you please explain more about this to me, how can avoid this.

Comment: I don't know how to change that but if it was me I would do one of the following 2 things: split it into 2 different plots or leave it as it is, if you remove those dates it could take you to a misleading conclusion about the data since your x-axis is not linear anymore

Answer (score 0):

How not to connect the gap, NA the data for that date, the line will be divided. Does this match the intent of the question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

date = pd.date_range('2020-05-6', periods=120, freq='H')
change = np.random.rand(120)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'change':change})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.loc[(df['date'] >= datetime.datetime(2020,5,8)) & (df['date'] < datetime.datetime(2020,5,9)), ['change']] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

x = list(np.arange(120))
ax.plot(df['date'], df['change'])
plt.show()
```

[image]